# Stacked Bar Chart In R Using 3 Columns

Tags: r

I am new to R and trying to create a stacked bar chart using 3 columns of data.  I am attempting to compare the degree of heart valve leakiness (measured in severity as 0, 1, 2, or 3) before a procedure, after a procedure, and at a follow-up time.  Below is a sample of the data I have.

| Subject | trpreop | trpostop | trfollowup |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 3 | 2 | 1 | 2 |
| 4 | 3 | 3 | 3 |

I essentially want to create 3 stacked bars with the proportion of "0, 1, or 2" being represented as the bar for each group ("trpreop, trpostop, trfollowup").  I tried looking through prior questions but nothing seemed to work correctly.  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
df %>% 
  pivot_longer(
    -Subject
  ) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=name, y=value, fill=factor(Subject)))+
  geom_col()
```

[image]

Comment: Except the subject should not be part of the graph.  So basically three bar graphs exactly as you have, but then filled with the percentage of "0", "1", "2", and "3" values that come up in each column.  So if "trfollowup" has 10 "1s" and 5 "2s" and 5 "3s" in its column, the bar graph would be 50% filled by "1", and 25% filled by "2" and "3".  The numbers actually represent a degree of severity (i.e. mild=1, moderate=2, severe=3).  Does that make sense?   This is definitely closer than I got though!